# What are "Descriptions" for?

Tags: ars-magica-5, ars-magica

In Ars Magica 5th, the Character Sheet has a space for a Description with each of the Characteristics. But I can't find in the book what is it for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are for **specialities**.

From Ars, 4th Edition:

> A speciality is simply a word that describes each non-zero
>   Characteristic your character has, giving more definition than a
>   statistic like "+2" or "-1" can. For example, if you have a +1
>   Strength, is your character "thick," "bulky," or "forceful"? Does your
>   -3 Dexterity indicate that he is "bumbling" or simply "clumsy". Characteristic specialities help you visualize your character, and
>   other than that, have no mechanical function in the game.

However. Examining the 5th edition book in detail I can't find any reference to "Description" at all (Checked all index'd references and other places I can think of, not read the whole thing again mind you!) so it looks like this item from 4th edition was lost in the editing from 4th -> 5th as far as I can tell. So, if this is the same as 4th it's purely for flavour and I can't find anything to contradict this (as I can't find anything that actually describes it) so it looks like the 5th has missed this, indeed in the character conversion section (p.224 ars 5th) it says

> Characteristics: Characteristics are unchanged between Fourth and
>   Fifth Editions

So I'm pretty confident that it's remained the same.

[image: 5th edition character sheet]

Comment: Which page is that on? I'm seeking for that paragraph in my spanish translation, and maybe they missed it!

Comment: I'll dig it up when I'm home.

Comment: Looks like they were lost in the edit between 4th and 5th; see my updated answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that in 3rd edition they had some mechanical effect as well - they were called "specialities" and you had +1 to that focus, didn't you? Or was that only in skills, and we somehow house-ruled that into characteristics as well?

Comment: Third Edition did have mechanical bonuses for the specialities, like skills if you had a applicable word descriptor; like "strong" and throwing a rock, then a +1 bonus applied. This didn't carry over for characteristics to 4th Edition, no, not answering any others - ask another question if you want the other editions! ;)

Comment: @lisardggY with characteristics it gets a little weird, if you have -1 does it mean you apply an additional -1 when the description applies?

Comment: @JoePerkins No, it's a 1 bonus above whatever your Characteristic is; -1, 0,1, 2, whatever, you'd get a +1 bonus to it if the Description was applicable (in 3rd edition at least)

Comment: @Rob Are you sure? If I remember correctly, when you have a negative bonus in a characteristic, the description has to be negative.

Comment: Good point, it's been a while!

Answer (score 1):

My guess for this appearing in the corebook is that they anticipated reintroducing them in some form so left that spot available.

What isn't a guess is that they do have a function in the expanded rules...for characters that choose to make use of them.

There are virtues and flaws in some of the expansion books that grant a keyword with a mechanical change to a Characteristic.  Specifically they appear in Realms of Power: Magic...but I'm sure I've seen them elsewhere.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take the [tour] when you get the chance. It's important to note that this is **not** a forum; responses should directly answer the question that was asked, rather than attempting to respond to other answers.